# Facebook Flash App (Desktop) Browser Descrepancies / OAuth Error. Why?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash

I am building a flash game that I have embedded in facebook. The actionscript api to login through facebook is the Player.io (Yahoo Games Network) as3 library.
Here is a link to the current game:
https://apps.facebook.com/blackjackbattledev/

It seems to work fine in Firefox browser (I'm using Windows 7), but then when I try to go to the game in Chrome or IE I get redirected to an error page with this text:

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 191    } }

When it goes to the error page the url in the address bar begins with https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize....
I am not sure why it is being redirected here. but the authentication shouldn't happen until the "facebook login" button is clicked so I don't know why I would be getting OAuth errors before even landing on the page. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help.

Comment: This was NOT a duplicate so thanks for closing my question, jerk.